# How to switch into other branch without commit and stash?

Tags: git

I have 2 branch which are branch_1 and branch_2.If my workspace is clean, I can checkout from one to another by using `git checkout branch_1/branch_2`

But sometimes the workspace is not clean so I have to commit or stash them before switch into another branch.So here is my question:

Is there any way that I can switch into another branch without `commit` or `stash`? I mean, I can switch the branch even if the workspace is not clean so that when I switch into this branch again , the workspace is as same as the last time I leave it.

Comment: `stash` exists to backup workspace changes without commiting. It's the tool for this specific problem. I don't see a reason not using it.

Comment: So you want to do a stash without having to do a stash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Git implements the contract that the working directory contents are updated to what you specify in your `git checkout` command's target parameter (e.g. branch name, SHA, or commitish).

Git won't checkout other branches if your working directory contains changes  incompatible with the target and it won't overwrite/lose what you have in your working directory. Hence the message stating you should either `git stash` or `git commit`.

You can `git checkout -f <SHA>`, but that would delete all changes to your working copy.